# How to assign new object to existing one

Tags: java, assign

I've got a problem with reading an object from file..

in main, I made eshop end call a method loadshop.

```
MyShop eshop = new MyShop();
eshop.loadShop("eshop.txt");
```

and also I'm getting the shop object from file.

```
@Override
public void loadShop(String filename) {

    try{
         ObjectInput out = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
         MyShop shop = (MyShop)out.readObject();
         out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I just can't figure out how to assign "shop" to "eshop"

Thank you for any answer..:-)  (Sorry for my English)

Comment: Define `assign`? What exaclty you want to do in that assignment? You mean create a copy of reference? Or create a copy of instance?

Comment: I'de expected `in.readObject();`.

Comment: I want to copy the content of shop (which I acquired from file) to already created instance (eshop).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the ```out``` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just redesign, you don't need to write

```
MyShop eshop = new MyShop();
```

Instead, write

```
MyShop eshop = MyShop.loadShop("eshop.txt");
```

and make the `loadShop` method static. And make it return the `MyShop` instance, if it isn't already doing that.

If this is not an option, it is still better to get that instance through a hack than to write manual copying code:

```
public class MyShop {
  private MyShop readShop;

  public MyShop getReadShop() { return readShop; }

  public void loadShop(String fName) {
    try {
       ObjectInput out = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
       this.readShop = (MyShop)out.readObject();
       out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You'd use this like

```
MyShop tempShop = new MyShop();
tempShop.loadShop();
MyShop eshop = tempShop.getReadShop();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but as I said above, I can't change it to static and make it return MyShop instance.. It's a homework (unfortunately)..:-(

Comment: I made that this way..:-) Thank you very, very much..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit all `eshop`'s fields, to match `shop`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `loadShop` method a `static` method. Make the method return the `MyShop` object. Call it on the `MyShop` class. Assign the return value to `eshop`. Example:

```
public class MyShop {
    public static MyShop loadShop(String filename) {
        // ...
        MyShop shop = (MyShop)out.readObject();

        // ...
        return shop;
    }
}
```

Where you call the method:

```
MyShop eshop = MyShop.loadShop("eshop.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. That's cool solution. But I unfortunately can't change the loadShop method to static and "Myshop" . It's homework from school and we mustn't change it..:-( It has to be " public void loadShop(String filename)"

Comment: If the method is `void` (it doesn't return a value) and not `static`, then what you have to do inside the method is set the member variables of the `MyShop` object that you're calling the method on.

Comment: And how should I do that please.. (Sorry, I'm beginner)

Comment: If the `loadShop` method you have added to your question cannot be changed, then this is an absolutely useless method. It is bacisally a no-op.

Comment: It can be changed of course, but I can't change the header of it..:-)

Comment: How about assigning the result from `readObject` into an instance variable, and then just getting that object from the outside by a getter?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks, but is it really impossible to use some command as `this = shop` ?..:-(

Comment: Absolutely not. Even if that **was** allowed, it would still achieve nothing.